# How do I insert values dynamically in this array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript calendar on an HTML website, and I'm new to javascript. One of the features of the calendar is the ability to add events for a certain day.

this is my script tag:-

```
<script>
  $(function (e) {
    var calendar = $("#calendar").calendarGC({
      dayBegin: 0,
      prevIcon: '&#x3c;',
      nextIcon: '&#x3e;',
      onPrevMonth: function (e) {
        console.log("prev");
        console.log(e)
      },
      onNextMonth: function (e) {
        console.log("next");
        console.log(e)
      },
      events: [
        {
          date: new Date("2022-09-26"),
          eventName: "Holiday",
          className: "badge bg-danger",
          onclick(e, data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          dateColor: "red"
        }
      ],
      onclickDate: function (e, data) {
        console.log(e, data);
      }
    });
  })
</script>
```

I want to dynamically add my custom values inside that **events:[]** array. Of course, I can edit it and add, but I want to create a function that takes values from me and adds them into it. I know how to create a function to get information from me, but I'm not sure how to push my information into that array. Thank in Advance :)

Additionally, if you require this calendar for additional study, I obtained it from this git: https://github.com/nggepe/calendar-gc

Answer (score 0):

using events.push()
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

```
calender.events.push({date:"2022-01-01",eventName:"new years day",className:"badge bg-danger",onclick(e,data){console.log(data)},dateColour:"green"})
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error = "Uncaught ReferenceError: events is not defined"

Comment: in this case, your main object is calendar. so you will need to push in to calendar.events, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: its giving this error now - Uncaught ReferenceError: calender is not defined

Comment: You have a function, which is passing in the parameter (e) on the second line. Your calendar variable is inside this function, which means you need to pass in your object (everything inside the curly braces) into this function as a parameter. You may need to review how functions work, and local/global scope. In short, the calendar variable does not exist anywhere except inside your function(e){}. If you want another function to be adding to the calendar, you need to reference the calendar first in that other function.